# How can I delete dynamically created fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which creates up to three new dropdown fields upon clicking the add button (+).

There is remove button (-) too. It is supposed to delete the most recently created field.

However, when I click on the remove button it does not remove the expected entry and I'm not sure why this is the case.

Finally, I want to be able to delete any new field that has been added by the add button.

```js
var clicks = 0
var update = 1

function add_item() {

  if (clicks < 2) {
    clicks += 1
    update += 1
    var x = document.createElement('div')
    var innerStuff = document.getElementById('hour_on_' + clicks).innerHTML
    var choiceLocation = document.getElementById("hour_on_" + clicks)
    x.innerHTML = innerStuff
    x.setAttribute("id", "hour_on_" + update)
    choiceLocation.appendChild(x)
  }

  function remove_item() {
    clicks -= 1
    update -= 1
    var elem = document.getElementById("hour_on_" + (update + 1))
    elem.remove()
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="hour_on_1">Floor Warm From:</label>
</div>

<div id="hour_on_1">
  <select class="hour_on" style="width:75px">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">1:00</option>
    <option value="1.25">1:15</option>
    <option value="1.5">1:30</option>
    <option value="1.75">1:45</option>
    <option value="2">2:00</option>
    <option value="2.25">2:15</option>
    <option value="2.5">2:30</option>
    <option value="2.75">2:45</option>
    <option value="3">3:00</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="add_item()" style=clear:both>+</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="remove_item()" style=clear:both>-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you nested your `remove_item()` function inside your `add_item()` function. You made it undefined outside of your `add_item()` function. I just pulled it out and made it its own function below.

```js
var clicks = 0;
var update = 1;

function add_item() {

  if (clicks < 2) {
    clicks += 1
    update += 1
    var x = document.createElement('div')
    var innerStuff = document.getElementById('hour_on_' + clicks).innerHTML
    var choiceLocation = document.getElementById("hour_on_" + clicks)
    x.innerHTML = innerStuff
    x.setAttribute("id", "hour_on_" + update)
    choiceLocation.appendChild(x)
  }
}

// I only pulled the below function outside of the above one ;) 

function remove_item() {
  if (clicks > 0) {
    clicks -= 1
    update -= 1
    var elem = document.getElementById("hour_on_" + (update + 1))
    elem.remove()
  }
  console.log('clicked')
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="hour_on_1">Floor Warm From:</label>
</div>

<div id="hour_on_1">
  <select class="hour_on" style="width:75px">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">1:00</option>
    <option value="1.25">1:15</option>
    <option value="1.5">1:30</option>
    <option value="1.75">1:45</option>
    <option value="2">2:00</option>
    <option value="2.25">2:15</option>
    <option value="2.5">2:30</option>
    <option value="2.75">2:45</option>
    <option value="3">3:00</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="add_item()" style=clear:both>+</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="remove_item()" style=clear:both>-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, I recommend looking into the naming conventions to avoid confusion when collaborating. Checkout things such as camelCase, snake_case, and other "cases" you'll run across when googling these terms.